# Why are Solve and LinearSolve returning different solutions here?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm working on a problem which requires me to take some numerical data I have from previous work, and use the data in the construction of new equations which I then have to solve. I can set up the equations fine, but when I try to use "Solve", I get the error "result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix may contain significant numerical errors". From other googling, it seems like this is because the coefficient matrix is sparse, but in the documentation for solve, it says that Solve can use efficient techniques for dealing with sparse systems, so I don't see why there is an error. I've tried using LinearSolve, but the system is underdetermined -- I need to throw in degree 2 polynomials as well, so the best I can do with it is show that a solution does exist. In the code below, I've included a part that solves it using LinearSolve and with solve. Solve returns no solution, but LinearSolve returns a solution. I don't understand why there is such a discrepancy. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate the help! I'll post my code below and I apologize in advance for the length of the numerical data, it can't be avoided.

```
matrix = {{(-2 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))/(-1 + 
       1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445])), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445])))}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.124201781 + 
     0.192207140 I, -0.041692902 - 0.225014152 I, 
    0.225058476 - 0.041452976 I, -0.108261054 + 0.201616495 I, 
    0.225098773 - 0.041233592 I, -0.116770009 - 0.196810650 I, 
    0.130858179 - 0.187738659 I, 0.157147780 + 0.166355770 I, 
    0.1291391972 + 0.1889252092 I, 0.0935608576 + 0.2088445183 I, 
    0.1291391972 + 0.1889252092 I, 0.157147780 + 0.166355770 I, 
    0.130858179 - 0.187738659 I, -0.116770009 - 0.196810650 I, 
    0.225098773 - 0.041233592 I, -0.108261054 + 0.201616495 I, 
    0.225058476 - 0.041452976 I, -0.041692902 - 
     0.225014152 I, -0.124201781 + 
     0.192207140 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.124201781 - 
     0.192207140 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.041692902 - 
     0.225014152 I, -0.135145338 + 0.184676486 I, 
    0.22097194 - 0.059506868 I, 
    0.221029839 - 0.059291459 I, -0.06334087 + 0.21990362 I, 
    0.10980448 + 0.20078008 I, -0.15122425 - 0.17175824 I, 
    0.214220133 - 0.080494729 I, 0.228780065 - 0.005417443 I, 
    0.228780065 - 0.005417443 I, 
    0.214220133 - 0.080494729 I, -0.15122425 - 0.17175824 I, 
    0.10980448 + 0.20078008 I, -0.06334087 + 0.21990362 I, 
    0.221029839 - 0.059291459 I, 
    0.22097194 - 0.059506868 I, -0.135145338 + 
     0.184676486 I, -0.041692902 - 
     0.225014152 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.041692902 + 
     0.225014152 I, -0.041692902 + 
     0.225014152 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225058476 - 0.041452976 I, 0.22097194 - 0.059506868 I, 
    0.05905577 + 0.22109293 I, 
    0.18699892 - 0.13191312 I, -0.20100376 + 
     0.10939449 I, -0.20119999 - 0.10903317 I, 
    0.20777208 + 0.09591888 I, -0.18920788 + 
     0.12872469 I, -0.20704123 + 0.09748638 I, -0.18920788 + 
     0.12872469 I, 
    0.20777208 + 0.09591888 I, -0.20119999 - 
     0.10903317 I, -0.20100376 + 0.10939449 I, 
    0.18699892 - 0.13191312 I, 0.05905577 + 0.22109293 I, 
    0.22097194 - 0.059506868 I, 
    0.225058476 - 0.041452976 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225058476 + 0.041452976 I, -0.13514534 - 0.18467649 I, 
    0.225058476 + 
     0.041452976 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.108261054 + 
     0.201616495 I, 0.221029839 - 0.059291459 I, 
    0.18699892 - 0.13191312 I, 
    0.04018518 - 0.22528830 I, -0.20109362 - 0.10922923 I, 
    0.01809696 - 0.22812752 I, -0.04399787 + 
     0.22457483 I, -0.19438146 - 0.12077050 I, -0.19438146 - 
     0.12077050 I, -0.04399787 + 0.22457483 I, 
    0.01809696 - 0.22812752 I, -0.20109362 - 0.10922923 I, 
    0.04018518 - 0.22528830 I, 0.18699892 - 0.13191312 I, 
    0.221029839 - 0.059291459 I, -0.108261054 + 
     0.201616495 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.108261054 - 0.201616495 I, 
    0.22097194 + 0.05950687 I, 
    0.22097194 + 0.05950687 I, -0.108261054 - 
     0.201616495 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225098773 - 0.041233592 I, -0.06334087 + 
     0.21990362 I, -0.20100376 + 0.10939449 I, -0.20109362 - 
     0.10922923 I, -0.18954396 + 0.12822930 I, -0.16961095 - 
     0.15362875 I, 
    0.17910505 + 0.14244665 I, -0.17594268 + 0.14633468 I, 
    0.17910505 + 0.14244665 I, -0.16961095 - 
     0.15362875 I, -0.18954396 + 0.12822930 I, -0.20109362 - 
     0.10922923 I, -0.20100376 + 0.10939449 I, -0.06334087 + 
     0.21990362 I, 
    0.225098773 - 0.041233592 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225098773 + 0.041233592 I, 0.22102984 + 0.05929146 I, 
    0.05905577 - 0.22109293 I, 0.22102984 + 0.05929146 I, 
    0.225098773 + 
     0.041233592 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.116770009 - 
     0.196810650 I, 
    0.10980448 + 0.20078008 I, -0.20119999 - 0.10903317 I, 
    0.01809696 - 0.22812752 I, -0.16961095 - 0.15362875 I, 
    0.07145824 - 0.21740144 I, -0.02196094 + 
     0.22778802 I, -0.02196094 + 0.22778802 I, 
    0.07145824 - 0.21740144 I, -0.16961095 - 0.15362875 I, 
    0.01809696 - 0.22812752 I, -0.20119999 - 0.10903317 I, 
    0.10980448 + 0.20078008 I, -0.116770009 - 
     0.196810650 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.116770009 + 
     0.196810650 I, -0.06334087 - 0.21990362 I, 
    0.18699892 + 0.13191312 I, 
    0.18699892 + 0.13191312 I, -0.06334087 - 
     0.21990362 I, -0.116770009 + 
     0.196810650 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.130858179 - 0.187738659 I, -0.15122425 - 0.17175824 I, 
    0.20777208 + 0.09591888 I, -0.04399787 + 0.22457483 I, 
    0.17910505 + 0.14244665 I, -0.02196094 + 
     0.22778802 I, -0.21646130 + 0.07425747 I, -0.02196094 + 
     0.22778802 I, 
    0.17910505 + 0.14244665 I, -0.04399787 + 0.22457483 I, 
    0.20777208 + 0.09591888 I, -0.15122425 - 0.17175824 I, 
    0.130858179 - 0.187738659 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.130858179 + 0.187738659 I, 
    0.10980448 - 0.20078008 I, -0.20100376 - 0.10939449 I, 
    0.04018518 + 0.22528830 I, -0.20100376 - 0.10939449 I, 
    0.10980448 - 0.20078008 I, 
    0.130858179 + 0.187738659 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.157147780 + 0.166355770 I, 
    0.214220133 - 0.080494729 I, -0.18920788 + 
     0.12872469 I, -0.19438146 - 0.12077050 I, -0.17594268 + 
     0.14633468 I, -0.02196094 + 0.22778802 I, -0.02196094 + 
     0.22778802 I, -0.17594268 + 0.14633468 I, -0.19438146 - 
     0.12077050 I, -0.18920788 + 0.12872469 I, 
    0.214220133 - 0.080494729 I, 
    0.157147780 + 0.166355770 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.157147780 - 0.166355770 I, -0.15122425 + 
     0.17175824 I, -0.20119999 + 0.10903317 I, -0.20109362 + 
     0.10922923 I, -0.20109362 + 0.10922923 I, -0.20119999 + 
     0.10903317 I, -0.15122425 + 0.17175824 I, 
    0.157147780 - 0.166355770 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.1291391972 + 0.1889252092 I, 
    0.228780065 - 0.005417443 I, -0.20704123 + 
     0.09748638 I, -0.19438146 - 0.12077050 I, 
    0.17910505 + 0.14244665 I, 0.07145824 - 0.21740144 I, 
    0.17910505 + 0.14244665 I, -0.19438146 - 
     0.12077050 I, -0.20704123 + 0.09748638 I, 
    0.228780065 - 0.005417443 I, 
    0.1291391972 + 0.1889252092 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))),
     0.1291391972 - 0.1889252092 I, 0.214220133 + 0.080494729 I, 
    0.20777208 - 0.09591888 I, 
    0.01809696 + 0.22812752 I, -0.18954396 - 0.12822930 I, 
    0.01809696 + 0.22812752 I, 0.20777208 - 0.09591888 I, 
    0.214220133 + 0.080494729 I, 
    0.1291391972 - 0.1889252092 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.0935608576 + 0.2088445183 I, 
    0.228780065 - 0.005417443 I, -0.18920788 + 
     0.12872469 I, -0.04399787 + 0.22457483 I, -0.16961095 - 
     0.15362875 I, -0.16961095 - 0.15362875 I, -0.04399787 + 
     0.22457483 I, -0.18920788 + 0.12872469 I, 
    0.228780065 - 0.005417443 I, 
    0.0935608576 + 0.2088445183 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))),
     0.093560858 - 0.208844518 I, 
    0.228780065 + 0.005417443 I, -0.18920788 - 
     0.12872469 I, -0.04399787 - 0.22457483 I, -0.16961095 + 
     0.15362875 I, -0.16961095 + 0.15362875 I, -0.04399787 - 
     0.22457483 I, -0.18920788 - 0.12872469 I, 
    0.228780065 + 0.005417443 I, 
    0.093560858 - 0.208844518 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.1291391972 + 0.1889252092 I, 0.214220133 - 0.080494729 I, 
    0.20777208 + 0.09591888 I, 
    0.01809696 - 0.22812752 I, -0.18954396 + 0.12822930 I, 
    0.01809696 - 0.22812752 I, 0.20777208 + 0.09591888 I, 
    0.214220133 - 0.080494729 I, 
    0.1291391972 + 0.1889252092 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))),
     0.1291391972 - 0.1889252092 I, 
    0.228780065 + 0.005417443 I, -0.207041233 - 
     0.097486382 I, -0.19438146 + 0.12077050 I, 
    0.17910505 - 0.14244665 I, 0.07145824 + 0.21740144 I, 
    0.17910505 - 0.14244665 I, -0.19438146 + 
     0.12077050 I, -0.207041233 - 0.097486382 I, 
    0.228780065 + 0.005417443 I, 
    0.1291391972 - 0.1889252092 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.157147780 + 0.166355770 I, -0.15122425 - 
     0.17175824 I, -0.20119999 - 0.10903317 I, -0.20109362 - 
     0.10922923 I, -0.20109362 - 0.10922923 I, -0.20119999 - 
     0.10903317 I, -0.15122425 - 0.17175824 I, 
    0.157147780 + 0.166355770 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.157147780 - 0.166355770 I, 
    0.214220133 + 0.080494729 I, -0.18920788 - 
     0.12872469 I, -0.19438146 + 0.12077050 I, -0.17594268 - 
     0.14633468 I, -0.02196094 - 0.22778802 I, -0.02196094 - 
     0.22778802 I, -0.17594268 - 0.14633468 I, -0.19438146 + 
     0.12077050 I, -0.18920788 - 0.12872469 I, 
    0.214220133 + 0.080494729 I, 
    0.157147780 - 0.166355770 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.130858179 - 0.187738659 I, 
    0.10980448 + 0.20078008 I, -0.20100376 + 0.10939449 I, 
    0.04018518 - 0.22528830 I, -0.20100376 + 0.10939449 I, 
    0.10980448 + 0.20078008 I, 
    0.130858179 - 0.187738659 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.130858179 + 0.187738659 I, -0.15122425 + 0.17175824 I, 
    0.20777208 - 0.09591888 I, -0.04399787 - 0.22457483 I, 
    0.17910505 - 0.14244665 I, -0.02196094 - 
     0.22778802 I, -0.21646130 - 0.07425747 I, -0.02196094 - 
     0.22778802 I, 
    0.17910505 - 0.14244665 I, -0.04399787 - 0.22457483 I, 
    0.20777208 - 0.09591888 I, -0.15122425 + 0.17175824 I, 
    0.130858179 + 
     0.187738659 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.116770009 - 
     0.196810650 I, -0.06334087 + 0.21990362 I, 
    0.18699892 - 0.13191312 I, 
    0.18699892 - 0.13191312 I, -0.06334087 + 
     0.21990362 I, -0.116770009 - 
     0.196810650 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.116770009 + 0.196810650 I, 
    0.10980448 - 0.20078008 I, -0.20119999 + 0.10903317 I, 
    0.01809696 + 0.22812752 I, -0.16961095 + 0.15362875 I, 
    0.07145824 + 0.21740144 I, -0.02196094 - 
     0.22778802 I, -0.02196094 - 0.22778802 I, 
    0.07145824 + 0.21740144 I, -0.16961095 + 0.15362875 I, 
    0.01809696 + 0.22812752 I, -0.20119999 + 0.10903317 I, 
    0.10980448 - 0.20078008 I, -0.116770009 + 
     0.196810650 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225098773 - 0.041233592 I, 0.221029839 - 0.059291459 I, 
    0.05905577 + 0.22109293 I, 0.221029839 - 0.059291459 I, 
    0.225098773 - 0.041233592 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225098773 + 0.041233592 I, -0.06334087 - 
     0.21990362 I, -0.20100376 - 0.10939449 I, -0.20109362 + 
     0.10922923 I, -0.18954396 - 0.12822930 I, -0.16961095 + 
     0.15362875 I, 
    0.17910505 - 0.14244665 I, -0.17594268 - 0.14633468 I, 
    0.17910505 - 0.14244665 I, -0.16961095 + 
     0.15362875 I, -0.18954396 - 0.12822930 I, -0.20109362 + 
     0.10922923 I, -0.20100376 - 0.10939449 I, -0.06334087 - 
     0.21990362 I, 
    0.225098773 + 
     0.041233592 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.108261054 + 
     0.201616495 I, 0.22097194 - 0.059506868 I, 
    0.22097194 - 0.059506868 I, -0.108261054 + 
     0.201616495 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.108261054 - 0.201616495 I, 
    0.22102984 + 0.05929146 I, 0.18699892 + 0.13191312 I, 
    0.04018518 + 0.22528830 I, -0.20109362 + 0.10922923 I, 
    0.01809696 + 0.22812752 I, -0.04399787 - 
     0.22457483 I, -0.19438146 + 0.12077050 I, -0.19438146 + 
     0.12077050 I, -0.04399787 - 0.22457483 I, 
    0.01809696 + 0.22812752 I, -0.20109362 + 0.10922923 I, 
    0.04018518 + 0.22528830 I, 0.18699892 + 0.13191312 I, 
    0.22102984 + 0.05929146 I, -0.108261054 - 
     0.201616495 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225058476 - 0.041452976 I, -0.135145338 + 0.184676486 I, 
    0.225058476 - 0.041452976 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), 
    0.225058476 + 0.041452976 I, 0.22097194 + 0.05950687 I, 
    0.05905577 - 0.22109293 I, 
    0.18699892 + 0.13191312 I, -0.20100376 - 
     0.10939449 I, -0.20119999 + 0.10903317 I, 
    0.20777208 - 0.09591888 I, -0.18920788 - 
     0.12872469 I, -0.207041233 - 0.097486382 I, -0.18920788 - 
     0.12872469 I, 
    0.20777208 - 0.09591888 I, -0.20119999 + 
     0.10903317 I, -0.20100376 - 0.10939449 I, 
    0.18699892 + 0.13191312 I, 0.05905577 - 0.22109293 I, 
    0.22097194 + 0.05950687 I, 
    0.225058476 + 
     0.041452976 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.041692902 - 
     0.225014152 I, -0.041692902 - 
     0.225014152 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.041692902 + 
     0.225014152 I, -0.13514534 - 0.18467649 I, 
    0.22097194 + 0.05950687 I, 
    0.22102984 + 0.05929146 I, -0.06334087 - 0.21990362 I, 
    0.10980448 - 0.20078008 I, -0.15122425 + 0.17175824 I, 
    0.214220133 + 0.080494729 I, 0.228780065 + 0.005417443 I, 
    0.228780065 + 0.005417443 I, 
    0.214220133 + 0.080494729 I, -0.15122425 + 0.17175824 I, 
    0.10980448 - 0.20078008 I, -0.06334087 - 0.21990362 I, 
    0.22102984 + 0.05929146 I, 
    0.22097194 + 0.05950687 I, -0.13514534 - 
     0.18467649 I, -0.041692902 + 
     0.225014152 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.124201781 + 
     0.192207140 I}, {-(1/(-1 + 
         1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445]))), -0.124201781 - 
     0.192207140 I, -0.041692902 + 0.225014152 I, 
    0.225058476 + 0.041452976 I, -0.108261054 - 0.201616495 I, 
    0.225098773 + 0.041233592 I, -0.116770009 + 0.196810650 I, 
    0.130858179 + 0.187738659 I, 0.157147780 - 0.166355770 I, 
    0.1291391972 - 0.1889252092 I, 0.093560858 - 0.208844518 I, 
    0.1291391972 - 0.1889252092 I, 0.157147780 - 0.166355770 I, 
    0.130858179 + 0.187738659 I, -0.116770009 + 0.196810650 I, 
    0.225098773 + 0.041233592 I, -0.108261054 - 0.201616495 I, 
    0.225058476 + 0.041452976 I, -0.041692902 + 
     0.225014152 I, -0.124201781 - 
     0.192207140 I, -(1/(-1 + 1/2 (21 + Sqrt[445])))}};
nu = 21;
d = (nu + Sqrt[nu^2 + 4])/2;
mu = nu^2 + 4;
listOfPossibleSols = {};
listOfValues = {};
w1[j_] := Exp[2 Pi I j/mu];
(*These are the linear equations needed.I didn't include the \
non-linear ones.I'm solving for the C[j,g,h]'s*)

eqs1 = Sum[C[j, 0, g], {g, 0, nu - 1}] - w1[j] + 
   Conjugate[w1[j]] 1/d;
eqs2 = Flatten[
  Table[w1[j]*C[j, g, h] - 
    Sum[matrix[[Mod[g + k, nu] + 1, Mod[2 h, nu] + 1]] C[j, h, k], {k,
       0, nu - 1}] - KroneckerDelta[h, 0] Conjugate[w1[j]] 1/d, {g, 0,
     nu - 1}, {h, 0, nu - 1}]]
AppendTo[eqs2, eqs1];
phi[x_, g_] := Exp[2 Pi I x g/nu];
eqn619 = Table[
   1 + Conjugate[phi[x, g]] w1[j] + 
    d w1[j] Sum[
      phi[x, m] C[j, q, 
        t] matrix[[Mod[t + m + g, nu] + 1, 
         Mod[q + m, nu] + 1]] matrix[[Mod[t - m - g, nu] + 1, 
         Mod[q - m, nu] + 1]], {t, 0, (nu - 1)}, {q, 0, (nu - 1)}, {m,
        0, (nu - 1)}], {g, 0, (nu - 1)}, {x, 0, (nu - 1)}];
DeleteDuplicates[Chop[eqn619]];
eqs = Flatten[Join[eqn619, eqs2]];
listOfVars = 
  Flatten[Table[C[j, g, h], {g, 0, nu - 1}, {h, 0, nu - 1}]];
(*Here's the actual solving.It's in a Do statement because in the \
full case I have to run over all j from 1 to 21^2+4. For the purposes \
of speed/testing,I am only looping over j=2,6,since I expect \
solutions to exactly one of those 2 cases*)

Do[Print[possibleSol = Solve[eqs == 0]];
  {bMat, solMat} = CoefficientArrays[eqs == 0];
  possibleSol2 = LinearSolve[Normal[solMat], -bMat];
  If[possibleSol2 != {}, 
   AppendTo[listOfPossibleSols, 
    Flatten[{w[j] -> w1[j], possibleSol2}]];
   AppendTo[listOfValues, j]], {j, {2, 6}}];
listOfPossibleSols
```

When I run this code, Solve returns no solutions, but LinearSolve does return a solution for j = 2.

Comment: If there is no solution LinearSolve might return a least square approximation iirc

Comment: @Bublinski Check that for `j=6` we have `Length[eqs]`=883 and `Length[listOfVars]`=441. Normally these numbers should be equal.